# How to get Bootstrap's affixed navlist style?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I've been playing around with Bootstrap for sometime. While I've always been able to get everything working. I've been considering it for an upcoming project which requires an affixed side-nav exactly like the one present in the [Twitter Bootstrap doc.](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html)

I've even tried to include these classes to my  element.

```
<ul class="nav nav-list affix-top">
```

Any bootstrap mavens here who could help me figure out what I'd need to add to get these up and working. Also, I've been unable to get the chevrons to display exactly as done over there, my chevrons always get mashed up together with the text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you remembered to turn it on in JS?

They use:

```
$('#navbar').affix()
```

, but you'll need to change the selector to whatever your need.

Ah, now you've rephrased what you want!

They have another class on that called `.bs-docs-sidenav`

```
.bs-docs-sidenav {
    width: 228px;
    margin: 30px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.065);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.065);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.065);
}
```

They then add a class called `active` to the li, then specify the behaviour of that here:

```
.bs-docs-sidenav > .active > a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 9px 15px;
    border: 0;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1), inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1), inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1), inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
```

So in short, that isn't a built in function of bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks but this is just for affixing the nav. I'm unable to recreate the visual style ((.nav-tabs stacked) comes close, but doesn't have that current selection highlight) of their nav-list.

Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: Thanks a ton. Also, would I need to tinker with JS for "active" to work properly?

Also, I actually wanted to add an image to this post to convey what I actually intended to, seems like I'm not able to do so yet.

Comment: I'm not sure, doesn't look like it. Guess you might need scrollspy as well to get it to highlight. That's OK! You'll get reputation pretty quickly!

Comment: What adds the `active` class to the LI ? is this part of the bootstrap.affix module?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and could not get mine to work until found this include on the bootstrap documents page.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/application.js

```
!function ($) {

  $(function(){

    var $window = $(window)

    // Disable certain links in docs
    $('section [href^=#]').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
    })

    // side bar
    $('.bs-docs-sidenav').affix({
      offset: {
        top: function () { return $window.width() <= 980 ? 290 : 210 }
      , bottom: 270
      }
    })          
  })
}(window.jQuery)
```

so adding the code abode while copying and pasting the bootstrap afix navigation should take care of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To get the same effect as the one on the github.io page you need the full css they added

```
<style type="text/css">

.bs-docs-sidenav > li > a {
    border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    /*display: block;*/
    /*margin: 0 0 -1px;*/
    padding: 8px 14px;
}

.bs-docs-sidenav > li > a {
    border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    /*display: block;*/
    /*margin: 0 0 -1px;*/
    padding: 8px 14px;
}

.bs-docs-sidenav > li:first-child > a {
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}

.bs-docs-sidenav > li:last-child > a {
    border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
}

.bs-docs-sidenav > .active > a {
    border: 0 none;
    box-shadow: 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset, -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    padding: 9px 15px;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    z-index: 2;
}

.bs-docs-sidenav .icon-chevron-right {
    float: right;
    margin-right: -6px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    opacity: 0.25;
}

.bs-docs-sidenav > li > a:hover {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.bs-docs-sidenav a:hover .icon-chevron-right {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.bs-docs-sidenav .active .icon-chevron-right, .bs-docs-sidenav .active a:hover .icon-chevron-right {
    /*background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png");*/
    opacity: 1;
}

.bbs-docs-sidenav.affix {
    top: 40px;
}

.bbs-docs-sidenav.affix-bottom {
    bottom: 270px;
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
}

</style>
```

include this in your template or html and follow the bootstrap side navigation format:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="span3 bs-docs-sidebar">
        <ul class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav">
          <li><a href="#overview"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Overview</a></li>
          <li><a href="#transitions"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Transitions</a></li>
          ....
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="span9">

      ....

      </div>
</div>
```